# Django get the Model name using ORM's related field name

Tags: django, django-models

I have a string like this `order__product__category__description` which is a related expression of my Django's model structure

Now I have a model called `Shipment`

`field = 'order__product__category__description'`

Here `description` is a column name of table/model `Category`. Here comes the question, just by having this model `Shipment` and this field string `order__product__category__description` how do I find these models `Order`, `Product`, `Category`.

My use-case is I need to store all the field_names of `Category` in a list. Any idea on how to connect the dots? having left with just two details `Shipment` & that field string.

First thing comes to mind is to split by `__` and to come up with a list like this `['order','product','category']` and to iterate the model `_meta` based on the field name. Any other elegant ways would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the related model from the model class (rather than the related instance from a model instance), you can use `_meta.get_field()` combined with `field.related_model` to get the related model class:

```
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist

model = Shipment
lookup = 'order__product__category__description'

for name in lookup.split('__'):
    try:
        field = model._meta.get_field(name)
    except FieldDoesNotExist:
        # name is probably a lookup or transform such as __contains
        break
    if hasattr(field, 'related_model'):
        # field is a relation
        model = field.related_model
    else:
        # field is not a relation, any name that follows is
        # probably a lookup or transform
        break
```

Then do with `model` what you want.

Comment: It takes patience to digest this question and to understand what I was really looking for. Great answer. Kudos ~

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand well. Anyway hope this you want.

```
field = 'order__product__category__description'
```

To get `product` from `Shipment` instance

```
product_var = ".".join(field.split("__")[:2])
```

Then

```
from operator import attrgetter
attrgetter(product_var)(shipment_instance)
```

Also you can get all related as a `tuple`

```
attrgetter(".".join(field.split("__")[:1]), ".".join(field.split("__")[:2]), ".".join(field.split("__")[:3]), ".".join(field.split("__")[:4]))(shipment_instance)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have split the string it into a list, as you said to these:

```
models = ['order', 'product', 'category']
```

First get the app label (a string) that each model refers to:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

app_labels = []

for model in models:
    app_labels.append(ContentType.objects.filter(model=model).values('app_label').first().get('app_label'))
```

Now you have both `model` names and `app` names. So:

```
from django.apps import apps

model_classes = []

for app, model in zip(app_labels, models):
    model_classes.append(apps.get_model(app, model))
```

Finally, get each model fields with the `_meta` attribute like you already know:

```
for model in model_classes:
    print(model._meta.get_fields())
```